# Implementing GIT Kit in .NET Web Api

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I'm attempting to implement the GITKit in a Asp .NET Web Api 2 application.
I followed the instructions on the google developer kit. When I go to my sign in page, it redirects to accountchooser.com. So far, so good. I have a google account shown, so I select it. The page reloads, but it is completely blank. No call is received on my sign in successful url. The javascript console shows:

**Uncaught Error: At least one sign in option should be specified! gitkit.js:250**

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong? How does one debug the various calls to see where things are going haywire?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your sign in html page where window.google.identitytoolkit.start() is called, you need to pass a configuration object to the start() method with signInOptions defined. Below is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/css/gitkit.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  var config = {
      apiKey: '...',
      signInSuccessUrl: '/',
      signInOptions: ["google", "password"]
  };
  window.google.identitytoolkit.start(
      '#gitkitWidgetDiv', // accepts any CSS selector
      config);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I have that code. The problem occurs after they select an account in account chooser.

Comment: When the browser shows a blank page after the user select an account from accountchooser.com, can you dump the html source of the blank page and paste here (you may remove the apiKey)?